# how to return value before deleting it?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I would like to jump over two nodes, in order to have access to penultimate node as well as last node:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node node_t;

//prototypes
node_t *create(int);
node_t *push(node_t *, node_t **);
node_t *shift(node_t *);

int main(void){
    node_t *h = 0;

    for(int i =0; i<23 ; i++)
        push(create(i+1),&h);

    shift(h);

}

node_t *create(int value){
    node_t *new = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    new->value=value;
    //new->next=0;
    return new;
}

node_t *push(node_t *new, node_t **head){
    new->next = *head;
    *head=new;
    return new;
}

node_t *shift(node_t *head){
    node_t *tmp = head; //do not change head pointer
    for(;tmp;tmp=tmp->next->next); //jump over 2 nodes, to have access to last node and penultimate
    node_t *last = tmp->next; //one before null node (the very last), the one I want return;
    tmp->next = 0; //now delete it, so last node will become penultimate one
    return last;
}
```

But that would gives - `command terminated`. I know i am returning null, but how can I return before delete the node? Because return is the last command to be executed, it has to be the last. But then I am returning 0. How to get from that?

Comment: @autistic456 It is unclear what you are trying to do with the list.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, `shift` -> is the opposite of `push` : you delete the last element/node and return it. It it the same logic as it in perl shift

Comment: @autistic456 More logically consistent would be to remove the first node because you have a singly-linked list that supports the FIFO model.

Comment: Skipping through the list two at a time is not a correct way to find the penultimate node. Go through the list one item at a time. Either stop when the link two ahead is null or stop when you reach the end but include code to remember the most recent items. Be sure to handle cases where the list has fewer than two items.

Comment: Your loop won't stop until `tmp` is NULL, then on the next line you dereference that with `tmp->next`.  Boom.

Answer (score 0):

Correct  way to find penultimate node, without crashing, and handling cases where there are less than 2 nodes in the list:

```
for(;tmp && tmp->next && tmp->next->next;tmp=tmp->next);

if (tmp && tmp->next && tmp->next->next {
   // tmp is the penultimate node
} else {
   // List does not have at least 2 nodes
}
```